# htaccess rewrite two domains to one domain with https, non-www, and directory trailing

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two domain names with a different suffix and what I would like to do is the following:

1. rewrite all urls from domain2 to domain1.
2. rewrite all the www urls to their non-www urls and redirect it to domain1
3. force HTTPS urls
4. I would like the rules to also affect the complete directory trailing so for example: http://www.domain2.net/shop/ would go to https://domain1.com/shop/

What I have right now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/domain1\.com" [R=301,L]
```

As you can see that partly does what I need but I am having a hard time figuring out how to incoperate the whole directory trailing, does anyone know the correct solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it works for items 1, 2 and 3.
For item 4, you need to put in parenthesis the part of the pattern you want to reuse in the rewritten part, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://domain1.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

- `^(.*)$`: starts with anything `.*`, until the end `$`".  Note that `.*` will match empty string as well.
- `$1` will replace the content between parenthesis into the rewrite part.
- Ex: `http://domain2.net/TATA.html` --> `https://domain1.com/TATA.html`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tried to get it to work tho the way you mentioned it (unfortunately it did not completely work) I took your last RewriteRule and made it look like this: 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/domain1\.com%{REQUEST_URI}" [R=301,L]

That seemed to work

Comment: Indeed, I left the `/` in there, I should not have...  I will correct my answer right away.